# Sequelize - always return arrays even when only one record is retrieved

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ngresource, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Postgres and Angular.js in the front-end.

I'm setting up some routes to expect arrays in the response:

```
'getData': {
  method: 'GET',
  // isArray: true,
  url: 'stuff/:id',
  params: {id: '@id'}
}
```

However, when only one record is retrieved Sequelize seems to return an object directly
rather than an array with one object in it, which breaks the resource:

```
Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

Is there a way of setting up Sequelize to always return arrays even if there's only one record retrieved?

Or, a clean way of wrapping the data when it gets to ng-resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik it should work out of the box with `isArray: false` (which should be the default.

Answer (score 4):

Angular should support object responses, but in any case:

`Model.find()` will return an object, `Model.findAll()` will return an array. You can just swap to using a `findAll`, if filtering on primary key it won't make much of a difference.

`Model.find()` also takes query parameters as it's second parameter so you should also be able to do `Model.find({where: ..}, {plain: false})` but that hasn't been tested and isn't exactly public API.